# VideoLAN settings for iPhone/iPad

Tags: itunes, dvd, vlc-media-player, video-conversion, ipad

What are VideoLAN settings to convert a DVD for playback on iPhone/iPad?

Comment: I extracted DVD, then converted VIDEO_TS files using H.264 video and AAC audio codecs. Even if playback is correct in Windows Media Player, playback on iPad is not fluid. Video frames are not displayed in correct order, like playing forward and backward several times per second.

Comment: Please show what settings you used, and possibly provide a sample.